# rename file in bourne shell

Tags: scripting, sh

I am trying to write a **bourne-shell** script that takes a directory as a parameter and look for images named ixxx.a and rename them to ixxx_a.img where "xxx means the extension number for exemple image files would be named i001.a , i002.a ,i003.a ...)
here what I tried

```
mv $1/f[0-9][0-9][0-9].a $1/f[0-9][0-9][0-9]_a.img
```

but it says that the DEST is not a directory.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `mv` is not this magic. [Larry Wall wrote a rename script in Perl](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch09_10.htm) that can be this bit more magical, but requires writing a tiny snippet of Perl code each time you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $1/f[0-9][0-9][0-9].a; do
  mv $i ${i%.a}_a.img
done
```

However, this does not consider blank spaces in the file/folder names. In this case you'd have to use `while` so you get one file name per line (see below for bonus). There are probably dozens of other ways, including `rename`.

```
find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "f[0-9][0-9][0-9].a"|while read i; do
  mv "$i" "${i%.a}_a.img"
done
```

**Edit:** Perhaps I should explain what I did there. It's called string substitution and the main use cases are these for a variable `var`:

```
# Get first two characters
${var:0:2}
# Remove shortest rear-anchored pattern - this one would give the directory name of a file, for example
${var%/*}
# Remove longest rear-anchored pattern
${var%%/*}
# Remove shortest front-anchored pattern - this  in particular removes a leading slash
${var#/}
# Remove longest front-anchored pattern - this would remove all but the base name of a file given its path
# Replace a by b
${var//a/b}
${var##*/}
```

For more see the `man` page.

Comment: if its not too much asked can you explain why `"${i%.a}_a.img"`

Comment: @biz: added some explanations so it's not just black magic to you.