# What does this mean SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}" in shell script?`

Tags: linux, sh

This code is from apache2 service starting script.

What does it mean?

```
SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527722

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It finds the name of the script being run, stripping out its directory. For instance if the script is `/etc/init.d/httpd` then this would set `SCRIPTNAME=httpd`.

`$0`, or `${0}`, is the name of the script being executed. The `##` operator is used to remove any leading string that matches the pattern `*/`. `*` is a wildcard character so `*/` means "any string followed by a forward slash".

The effect of this is to remove any leading directory names from `$0`, leaving just the name of the script.

From **man bash**:

> **${parameter#word}**
>   **${parameter##word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as  in  pathname  expansion.   If  the  pattern
>                 matches  the  beginning  of  the  value  of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the
>                 expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the "#" case) or the longest
>                 matching pattern (the "##" case) deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and  the  expansion  is  the  resultant
>                 list.   If  parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant  list.

Answer (score 2):

The left side is easy: it assigns to the variable `SCRIPTNAME`.
The right side is more complicated:

- `$0` or `${0}` is the name used to invoke the current shell or script.
- `${VAR##pattern}` is the value of variable `$VAR` with the longest string that matches the `pattern` removed from the beggining (use one `#` for the shortest or `%`/`%%` to remove the end.

So your expression removes the start of the name used to call the script up to, and including, the last slash.

BTW, that is what the program `basename` does.

Comment: Is that `##` POSIX portable, or is it bash only?  I still generally use `basename` to do this.